Commutation of $XX$ and $ZZ$ operators
It is known that the Pauli operators $XX$ and $ZZ$ commute. Consider the state $\vert{++}\rangle$ which is an eigenstate of $XX$. But we also know that
$$ZZ\vert{++}\rangle = \vert{--}\rangle$$
so this is not an eigenstate of $ZZ$. I thought that commuting operators would have a common set of eigenstates. What is the mistake in my thinking?

TL;DR: The cause of the apparent paradox is degeneracy: each of the two operators has (infinitely) many eigenbases. One of the eigenbases is shared, but it does not contain $|{++}\rangle$. The shared eigenbasis consists of the four entangled Bell states.
Fact 1. Suppose two normal operators commute. This implies that there exists a common eigenbasis. It does not imply that every eigenbasis of one is also an eigenbasis of the other.
Fact 2. If the spectrum of a normal operator is non-degenerate (in other words, if its eigenvalues are all distinct), then it has only one eigenbasis.
Consequently, if two commuting operators have non-degenerate spectra, then every eigenvector of one is indeed an eigenvector of the other. However, the spectrum of $XX$ (and of $ZZ$) is the multiset $\{-1, -1, +1, +1\}$ which is degenerate, so an eigenvector of $XX$ is not necessarily an eigenvector of $ZZ$ and vice versa.
Notice that the $+1$ eigenspace of $ZZ$ is spanned by $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ and the $-1$ eigenspace of $ZZ$ is spanned by $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$. Thus, for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$, the two orthonormal states
\begin{align}
\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle,\quad\overline{\beta}|00\rangle-\overline{\alpha}|11\rangle\tag1
\end{align}
span the $+1$ eigenspace of $ZZ$. Similarly, the two orthonormal states
\begin{align}
\alpha|01\rangle+\beta|10\rangle,\quad\overline{\beta}|01\rangle-\overline{\alpha}|10\rangle\tag2
\end{align}
span the $-1$ eigenspace of $ZZ$. Thus, we have a continuum infinity of eigenbases of $ZZ$! Only one$^1$ of them is also an eigenbasis of $XX$.

$^1$ After ignoring the global phase.

Commuting operators share a set of eigenvectors that form a basis of the respective Hilbert space (in the finite dimensional case).
Here are the 4 common eigenvectors of XX and ZZ that form a basis of the 2-qubit Hilbert space:
$$|\Phi^\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\rangle \pm |11\rangle)$$
$$|\Psi^\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|01\rangle \pm |10\rangle)$$
Notice, however that the respective eigenvalues are not necessarily the same.
For example:
$$ XX|\Psi^+\rangle = +1 |\Psi^+\rangle$$
$$ ZZ|\Psi^+\rangle = -1 |\Psi^+\rangle$$
And this is the reason why there are eigenvectors for one operator which are not eigenvectors for the other operator.
Making it specific to your case:
$|++\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|\Phi^+\rangle + |\Psi^+\rangle)$
So, we get:
$$ XX|++\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(XX|\Phi^+\rangle + XX|\Psi^+\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|\Phi^+\rangle + |\Psi^+\rangle) = |++\rangle$$
and:
$$ ZZ|++\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(ZZ|\Phi^+\rangle + ZZ|\Psi^+\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|\Phi^+\rangle + (-1) |\Psi^+\rangle) = |--\rangle$$
